# JS/HTML: adding comments to a website w/out a database and backend

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to add a commenting feature to a website w/ HTML or JS only, i.e. w/out using a database or a backend?

Comment: Well I wouldn't think so, due to the fact that you would need a backend to process comment transactions (dependent on the case), and a database to further store those comments. Would be interested to see other people's solutions to this though.

Comment: you could use a service with a free tier - e.g. disqus.com, where you are just embedding a small amount of JS and then they are hosting the comments for you.  Aside from that, no, I can't think of a way you could have comments without a backend.

Comment: No you can’t do that. You can store it in local storage or cookies though but the comments will only be visible to the user itself who posted it.

Answer (score 3):

No, you *will* need a database/store for your data, without this how will other people be able to read other messages? It would be client-side only.

*You could just use a different website.*

> Is there a way to add a commenting feature to a website w/ HTML or JS only, i.e. w/out using a database or a backend?

This fails to answer the question correctly.

Comment: You mean I could use a different website as a "database", thus dispensing w/ *at least* the backend? Or that I still need a backend but not a database, as I'd be using a website instead?